# Floated classic treelist closes on click to expand

Tags: extjs

Even in the sencha kitchen sink example, when in micro mode, the first time you click on a nested treelist, the whole floated treelist will close and throw this console error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'un' of null

You can see the bug at https://examples.sencha.com/extjs/7.0.0/examples/kitchensink/?classic#tree-list

You just have to hover over home, and then click to expand 'admin'.

Does anyone have a fix for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats happen because method `onRefresh` of `treelist`  which been called from `expand` by implication. In `onRefresh` extjs remove current root and create it newly.

```
            me.removeRoot();

            if (root) {
                me.createRootItem(root);
            }
```

We need to add a check of condition `getMicro`.
I  created override:

```js
Ext.define('Ext.list.TreeOverride', {
    override: 'Ext.list.Tree',
    privates: {
    onRootChange: function (root) {
        var me = this;
        if (!me.getMicro()) {
            me.removeRoot();
            if (root) {
                me.createRootItem(root);
            }
            me.updateLayout();
        }
        me.fireEvent('refresh', me);
    }
    }
});
```

and [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/32t1) with fixed kitchen sink example

Comment: Thanks!! How did you find that that was the problem function?

Comment: Also, in your fiddle, when you uncheck 'expander only', the treelist kind of bugs out when you click on the root nodes. Do you know how to fix that, or which function would be the function to look at?

Comment: Found it during a deep debug. Interesting bug.

Comment: What kind of bug do you mean? I can not reproduce. Describe in more detail

Comment: I guess maybe it is not a bug, I just don't like the behavior. But, if you are in micro mode, and you hover over home, and then click 'Home', it collapses the nodes below. If you click on the Home icon repeatedly, instead of hovering, it also expands and collapses the nodes.

Comment: I changed the behavior now to how I like by overiding onNodeCollapse: onNodeCollapse: function(node) {
            var item = this.itemMap[node.internalId];

            if (item.treeItemFloated) {
                return
            }
            if (item) {
                item.nodeCollapse(node, this.collapsingForExpand);
            }
        }